# Transitive project dependencies when dependency has a zip artifact

Tags: gradle

Typically, I define project dependencies simply:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':someProject')
}
```

This works well for java projects. However, I have a project that produces a zip artifact:

```
artifacts {
    archives file: zipDistribution.archivePath, type: 'zip', builtBy: zipDistribution
}
```

And when I do the dependency definition above, I don't get the zip artifact when I iterate over the dependencies in the compile configuration. A jar file is there, but no zip. This, however, gets the zip file:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(path: ':someProject', configuration: 'archives')
}
```

Great! It works! Except "someProject" has its own dependencies... and we're not getting those transitively any more. Adding `transitive: true` to the project dependency didn't help, either.

How can I get the project's zip artifact AND the transitive dependencies associated with it? I can add both flavors of dependencies, but I feel there's got to be a way to do it in one dependency definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `archives` configuration contains the artifacts to be uploaded, but it doesn't contain any dependencies. Try this instead:

```
dependencies {
    runtime ...
}

artifacts {
    runtime zipDistribution // assuming this is a `Zip` task
}
```

---

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':someProject')
}
```

Instead of the Java plugin's `runtime` configuration, the former script can also add dependencies and artifacts to a custom configuration, which would then have to be reflected in the project dependency (`project(path: ..., configuration: ...)`).